Reduce hair particle count without losing grooming?
I've been given an asset with tons of hair particles, which, if translated to hair cards, end up putting verts in the multiple millions.

I need to reduce the polycount drastically for this to be ready for UE5, but I can't modify the particle count unless I Delete Edit, but that leads to a really lousy-looking result:

Deleting Edits removes all the grooming, and for some reason, even though all the properties' numbers are the same after deleting them, the length of the particles is halved, and I'm left with an ungroomed mess:

Is there any way to preserve the asset's grooming, decrease the particle count, and export hair cards that aren't blowing up people's computers?
Or is there a way to reduce the particle count sufficiently to just export the fur alembic to UnReal without any hitches?
Thank you!

Can you explain how you converted the particles into hair cards? The conversion should reduce, but not increase, the required number of vertices. Have you converted only the hair particles (=good) or the hair particles + their children (=bad)?  For example, here is a model with hair cards: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/furry-bear-8cec0e6615574edf9ffd4ef45338e0da Stop the animation and turn on Wireframe mode in the Model Inspector (key I or icon at bottom right) to see them. According to the description it has only ~48k vertices.

What do your hair cards look like? Usually, they have a hair strand on them. Your hair cards don't have a single hair on them, do they?

@Blunder I'm mainly trying to follow this this tutorial. The process I know is to first convert the particle system to mesh, then to convert the resulting object to curves, but the sheer number of particles has that taking a long time, and I haven't seen any settings that would give me control over whether the children are being converted, which means I'm not really able to get to the stage where each card has its strand.

@Blunder There's also an issue where while the guy in the tutorial uses, as he says, Ctrl+T to "tilt" the curves so that they line up better with the source mesh, that doesn't seem to work for me, so I can't get them to be anything but either perpendicular to the surface or all basically aligned together wherever they are on the mesh.
